# Using enum values in array indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, sorting, enums

I have a byte array with some data stored at specific indexes. I want to assign these data to labels, but my current code looks messy. I was thinking about using enums to make the code more readable, but the problem is that when we use enums as array indexes, we need to cast them to integers, like this: **[(int)enum.blabla]**. This leads to repeated code and makes it look bad. Is there a way to write this code more cleanly? Can someone help me with this?

Example code:

```
enum CarSpeeds
{
    CarBlue = 1,
    CarRed = 2,
    CarYellow = 3
}

byte[] myByte = new byte[size];

LabelCarBlueSpeed.Text = myByte[(int)CarSpeeds.CarBlue] + " km/h";
LabelCarBlueSpeed.Text = myByte[(int)CarSpeeds.CarRed] + " km/h";
LabelCarBlueSpeed.Text = myByte[(int)CarSpeeds.CarRed] + " km/h";
```

We always have to use **(int)**
`myByte[CarSpeeds.CarRed] + " km/h";` while we can use `myByte[(int)CarSpeeds.CarRed]`

**Edit**: The "CarSpeeds" enum used in the previous example was just for the sake of illustration and to make it easier to understand. I'm not particularly fond of arrays myself, but since I'm reading data from a PLC, I need to use a byte array (buffer). My aim was to make my code more readable, that's all.

Comment: Don't use an array but a distinct class implementing an indexer for your enum. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: This looks like a job for a dedicated `Car` class and a `Dictionary` to look up the instances. If you add more than speed, for example, arrays are quickly going to turn into a big mess. Keep things together.

Comment: The "car" enum used in the previous example was just for the sake of illustration and to make it easier to understand. I'm not particularly fond of arrays myself, but since I'm reading data from a PLC, I need to use a byte array (buffer). My aim was to make my code more readable, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that enumeration can use *arbitrary* values, e.g.

```
    enum CarSpeeds
    {
        CarSubZero = -123456789, // <- Negative value
        CarBlue = 1,
        CarRed = 2,
        CarYellow = 3, 
        // Hole at 4
        CarBlack = 5,
        CarInfinity = 1_000_000_000, // <- Very high value
    }
```

that's why *array* can be not the best collection to use in your case. You can try *dictionary* instead (with key of `CarSpeeds` type):

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Create dictionary and initialize it as if it is an array:
// All keys are corresponding to default values
Dictionary<CarSpeeds, byte> myByte = Enum
  .GetValues<CarSpeeds>()
  .ToDictionary(key => key, key => default(byte));

...

myByte[CarSpeeds.CarSubZero] = 123;
myByte[CarSpeeds.CarInfinity] = 45;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update
what about a class?

```
class Car
{
    private readonly Label _label;
    private int _speed;

    public Car(Label label, string color)
    {
        _label = label;
        Color = color;
    }

    public string Color { get; }
    public int Speed { get => _speed; set { _speed = value; _label.Text = value + " km/h"; } }
}


public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _blueCar = new Car(LabelCarBlueSpeed, "blue"),
    _redCar = new Car(LabelCarRedSpeed, "red"),
    _yellowCar = new Car(LabelCarYellowSpeed, "yellow")
    _cars = new[] { _blueCar, _redCar, _yellowCar };
}
```

**Update:** from the comment it sounds more like parsing a buffer of data

```
class CarData
{
    private readonly byte[] _buffer;

    public CarData(byte[] buffer)
    {
        _buffer = buffer;
    }

    public byte BlueCarSpeed { get => _buffer[8]; set => _buffer[8] = value; }
    public byte RedCarSpeed { get => _buffer[10]; }
    public byte YellowCarSpeed { get => _buffer[12]; }
}
```

Comment: The "CarSpeeds" enum used in the previous example was just for the sake of illustration and to make it easier to understand. I'm not particularly fond of arrays myself, but since I'm reading data from a PLC, I need to use a byte array (buffer). My aim was to make my code more readable, that's all.

Comment: @MertAtmaca I used to work with a big buffers myself. I wrote a wrapper which got the bytes and had properties for everthing. When working in WPF it is also nice to bind to these.